# highchart dataLabel diffent position

Tags: highcharts

I have [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/VWYMW/) for the code below:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                align: 'left',
                enabled: true,
                rotation: 270,
                x: 2,
                y: -10
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
  });
});
```

I want to show dataLabels up and down(e.g. show points Jan/Mar/May above the line, show points (Feb/Apr/Jun below the line). Anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what you mean? Would you say that in the fiddle, the data labels are in correct position for Jan/Mar/May? What about the rest of the months?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve that is you override the x, y position of every individual point by passing it through the data object:

```
series: [{
        data: [
            { y: 29.9, dataLabels: { x: 0, y: 30 } }, 
            { y: 71.5, dataLabels: { x: 0, y: -10 } }, 
            { y: 106.4, dataLabels: { x: 0, y: 40 } }, 
            { y: 129.2, dataLabels: { x: 0, y: -10 } }, 
            { y: 144.0, dataLabels: { x: 0, y: 30 } }, 
            { y: 176.0, dataLabels: { x: 0, y: -10 } }, 
            { y: 135.6, dataLabels: { x: 0, y: 30 } }, 
            { y: 148.5, dataLabels: { x: 0, y: -10 } }, 
            { y: 216.4, dataLabels: { x: 0, y: 40 } }, 
            { y: 194.1, dataLabels: { x: 0, y: -10 } }, 
            { y: 95.6, dataLabels: { x: 0, y: 30 } },
            { y: 54.4, dataLabels: { x: 0, y: -10 } }
        ]        
    }]
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aYMGD/)

The above quick solution works well for the static data, but it is tedious if there are lots of data. And it can't change the data labels dynamically. So here is another solution which is more generic. It sets the data label after the chart is rendered.

```
$.each(chartObj.series[0].data, function(i, point) {
    console.log('point: ', point);
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        point.dataLabel.attr({y: point.dataLabel.y - 15});
    } else {
        point.dataLabel.attr({y: point.dataLabel.y + 35});
    }
});
```

[Another fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/c7HTX/2/)

Comment: As @Sualkcin mentioned, my previous answer doesn't work well if someone wants to change the data label dynamically. I updated it with another solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: Only problem will be with redraw - when hide/show series dataLabels have wrong position. To prevent this, use `chart.evets.redraw` with the same function.

Comment: @PawełFus - can you show an example of how to use the `cart.events.redraw` ?

Comment: You can find an example in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw).